# Translation of the "Funniest Joke in the World" (from the Monty Python sketch)

Tags: german-to-english

Recently saw [this Monty Python Sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwbnvkMRPKM).

**In brief:**

During WW2, the British (inadvertently) create a killer-joke. It isn't long before they decide to create a German version of the joke. Joke wrecks havoc on German troops. Germans decide to come up with a joke of their own ( the *V-Joke*).

The British joke is mentioned at 4:52 (not very clear) and at 7:36.

The German joke is mentioned at 8:32.

Could someone translate these please?

Comment: All translation would kill that joke, really. But later on you can hear what the German's translation came up with ;)

Comment: According to the sublime standards of this forum, you should first try and make your own translation; for specific problems evolving, your specific question is welcome.

Comment: @Christian I couldn't hear/make head or tail of what they were saying >_<

Comment: Yes, after I read the answer below, I understood why... .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The V-joke is not German at all.

[German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_t%C3%B6dlichste_Witz_der_Welt) quotes it as

> Wenn ist das nun Stück gitt (geht) und Schlottermeyer? - Ja: Bayer-Hund. Das, oder die Flipper-Wald Gespütt! (Gespött)“

This is *made up* to sound like German, but doesn't make any sense. It's obvious the joke had to be modified beyond distinction - Way too dangerous otherwise.

Comment: I had this *really* strong feeling the "joke" was gibberish, thanks! XD

Comment: Das ist die Version der deutschen Synchronfassung, im Original klingts anders.

Comment: @Takkat Nein, der Text ist derselbe. Die englische Wikipedia transkribiert ein bißchen anders als: "Wenn ist das Nunstück git und Slotermeyer? Ja! Beiherhund das Oder die Flipperwaldt gersput". Das bedeutet exakt dasselbe ;)

Comment: @tofro: habe mir den Sketch nochmal angehört... an welcher Stelle meinst du, dass sie diesen Text sprechen?

Comment: 6:03, 7:36. Oder im folgenden Transkript: http://www.montypython.net/scripts/funniest.php